# Expand minified css file with text editor

Tags: css, sublimetext2, notepad++, minify

A site I took over is currently set to use the `.min` version of a css file. `.min` is great for users, but pretty terrible for testing and development. Is there a way using sublime text or another text editor that I can expand the text to standard formatting and spacing?

Answer (score 8):

you can use tools like this...

http://www.cleancss.com/css-beautify/

just copy paste both ways

else search on google for css beautifier